# Rails devise confirmable : authorize first sign in at sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I use devise 3.0.3

I have a confirmable model.

I'd like the user to be signed in at first sign up during the whole session, and then when the user comes back, he must be confirmed. The idea is not to break the signup navigation flow by having to check emails.

Another option would be to give the user a 24h delay before being rejected from logging in.

I tried to use `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` this way :

```
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(user)
    user.confirm!
    sign_in(:user, user)
    user.confirmed_at = nil
    user.save
    return user_path(user)
  end
```

but I still get rejected at the end.

Any suggestion do to this properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question.

In your User model, add this class method

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.allow_unconfirmed_access_for
    1.day # Or any time frame you like
  end
end
```

There is a method named `confirmation_period_valid?` in `Devise::Models::Confrimable`. This method will check the above mentioned class method which by default does not exist and expect nil.

If you have set such time, Devise will allow this user's signing in within this period, even he is not confirmed.

You don't need any change on controller.

*Disclaimer: I have not used this solution before but just concluded it by browsing source. In theory it should work.*

Comment: Thanks! I've been searching for this option but could not find it. It's actually in devise default initializer : `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 1.day
`, though it certainly works in the model especially if one has several devise models with different parameters.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger, nice tip about config, I havn't checked that :)